# Should Dr. (Indiana) Jones do it? Another Jones Adventure

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

This puzzle is linked to the previous " Should Dr. (Indiana) Jones do it?" puzzle

After walking thru the rain drenched tropical forest Jones finally arrived at his destination. A stone building with what looked like 4 similar looking doors and a veranda in front of them. The stone looked like dark granite. The doors looked metallic, brass or bronze may be. There were no windows.

He walked into the veranda and saw a Tape Recorder in the corner. He turned it on. The deep voice said:

> **Welcome again Doctor Jones. I have been expecting you. If you have
>   come looking for the Chinese Golden Dragon, you have found the place.
>   It is stored safely in one of these 4 rooms, in a cabinet on the back
>   wall. All you have to do is to push open the door of that room, walk
>   across, open the cabinet and take the treasure. So simple.
>
> Well, there is a tiny bit of problem Doctor Jones. I have made this a
>   little bit more challenging than the last time. Last time you only had
>   to deal with 2 rooms, one with the acid shower and one safe. You were
>   lucky enough to guess the right one. But this time, there are 4
>   identical looking rooms. Three are death traps and, the fourth is
>   safe. The treasure is in the safe room.
>
> Now all rooms look the same. Same walls, ceilings and same closed
>   cabinets. They all have holes in the walls and ceilings. Yes Doctor
>   Jones, the holes have a deadly purpose of course!
>
> Randomly, Room 1 is the Acid room, and is plumbed with concentrated
>   acid shower. Once you are in the room, acid spray from all directions
>   coming thru the holes will drench you. Not fun.
>
> Room 2 is the Bullet room. Once you are in the room bullets will fly
>   from the holes and I am certain that some of them will definitely hit
>   you.
>
> Room 3 is the Furnace room. Once inside the holes will breathe and
>   spray ultra-hot gas from all directions which will melt your skin. Not
>   fun either.
>
> Room 4 is the room you want Jones. Safe room. Pick that room, walk
>   across, open the cabinet and take the treasure.
>
> Now I remember that last time there may have been a slight
>   miscalculation on my part about the acid shower. This time I have
>   corrected the problem. Also just before you arrived I have tested all
>   the death rooms to make sure everything works.
>
> Now all you have to do is guess the right room, open the door, run to
>   the cabinet, take the treasure and go back thru the open door. The
>   door is on a timer. It will remain open for 20 seconds only and will
>   then automatically close and lock. The sensors for the acid, the
>   bullets and the hot gases are triggered the moment you crack open the
>   doors but the actual showers start after 2 or 3 seconds. Oh and Jones,
>   once you open any door the other doors are locked and you cannot get
>   in.
>
> Good luck Doctor Jones. Hopefully this will be the last time we talk.**

Jones thought about it. He could open a door and wait a few seconds to watch if there are death showers. But then the other doors will be locked. And 20 seconds is not a lot of time. He did not bring anything with him except his whip and some food.

The he walked across the veranda and stopped in front of one of the doors. He was just about to turn the handle when he stopped and slowly let it go. He walked to the adjacent door and turned the handle slowly. He then entered the room.

Why did he do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

> He first examined all of the doors.  He was able to see damage to two of them from bullets and acid respectively, so those two were trap rooms 
>  When he touched the door handle of one of the remaining two doors, it was still hot from the furnace test, so it was a trap room 
>  He slowly removed his hand before triggering the trap 
>  He went to the last door and opened it and he went in.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the bullet room would have had a damaged door (from the test) and the acid room would also have a damaged door from the acid corroding the door handle.

Comment: @steveV  According to the OP once you open the door the other doors get locked!

Comment: @DEEM i meant to say that had that not been the right room, he'd be out of luck... edited my answer accordingly

Comment: So here is the solution. Jones looks at all the doors. Only 2 doors show the damage from the bullets and the acid. So he has 2 choces left. He touches the door handle and senses the heat. So he lets that go and goes to the remaining door

Comment: @DEEM should I edit that in?

Comment: @SteveV  Yes please do so then I will accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

Jones guessed all three bad doors,

> while he walked across the veranda he examined there were blood stains on the floor near one of the door, this must be the door where bullets are planned. Blood spilled from the man who tested it.
>  next door had some kind of burning smell, this must be the fire room, so he went ahead to examine next door.
> he saw the remaining two doors nor the floor close the them have no signs of anything, so he decided he would open any of those two doors.
> he said,
>  ***Akkad bakkad bambe Bo..
> assi nabbe poore sau..***
> when he approached randomly chosen door he noticed the metallic/brass/bronze door has corroding layer, so he let it go and approached the next door and entered safely..

Also

> the voice on the radio was extremely deep, he must have suffered lot of burns and injuries while testing all the doors

Answer (score 2):

Though @SteveV's answer is great, I would like to pose another theory. The story states that Dr. Jones walked the corridor and stopped between two doors. He somehow figured out that the first two doors were traps, leaving just two rooms. Now, @SteveV's answer makes sense, but I don't think Dr. Jones would have slowly released the handle in that case.

> I believe the door handle he had ahold of was in fact the acid room and he slowly turned the handle because he was trying to locate the sound of the corroding metal. Once he established that it was coming from the inner portion of the door he was in front of, he slowly released the handle as to not trip the locks on the other doors, and went into the room he determined to be safe by logical deduction.

Another theory is that Dr. Jones just followed the numbers given.

> In sequential order from the tape recorder he counted the doors; one, two, three, ahhh here we are. But he stopped as he was about to open the door completely and remembered; oh, the deep voice had to walk across the Veranda to place the tape, so he had calculated right to left, instead of left to right. He then released the handle, and simply opened the fourth door.

Now, I know the second theory here is probably highly incorrect, but it was worth a thought!

Comment: If you down-vote my answer, please explain as to how I can improve it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and understand that the second theory might be far-fetched, so perhaps that's why it was down-voted? But your first theory is pretty good :P